# Most efficient way to write same object to a database using OO with Java

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm computing for android. I try to be carefull about memory leaks because my program is dealing with lots of data, and the garbage collector seems to be very busy.

I was wondering is there a difference beetween :

```
for (int i=0;i<200;i++) 
{
   MyObject myobject = new MyObject(i,i+1);
   myobject.writeToDatabase();
}
```

and

```
MyObject myobject=null;
for (int i=0;i<200;i++) 
{
    myobject = new MyObject(i,i+1);
    myobject.writeToDatabase();
}
```

and (avoiding to use the constructor)

```
MyObject myobject=new MyObject(0,1);
myobject.writeToDatabase();
for (int i=1;i<200;i++) 
{
   myobject.setFirstValue(i);
   myobject.setSecondValue(i+1);
   myobject.writeToDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Unless there's a bug in the operating system itself, none of the above cause memory leaks.  A memory leak is when the pointer to a block of allocated memory is discarded  before the memory is freed. That's possible in C or C++, but not in languages like Java and C# which do the garbage collection for you.  In any case, as @Arno-Sluismans says, the third option is the most efficient.

Comment: @Stochastically, thanks for that input, I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third option is by far the best. The two other options are pretty much identical in Java, in that context.

If you do not create a new object every time, and instead use the old one again, you are relieving your garbage collector of a lot of work. This is a good way to make your performance and memory management a lot more efficient.

In the two first options, you are basically doing the same thing: making a new object at the beginning of the loop, and letting it get destroyed at the end of the loop. The fact that you keep using the same variable for the pointer doesn't make much of a difference.

**Edit:**

As said by [Stochastically](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110762/stochastically), your code would not cause any memory leaks though, simply for the fact that the garbage collector will make sure that doesn't happen. I'm guessing that there are some tricks to cause memory leaks after all, but in normal situations that just won't happen. But as I explained, you still have ways to make your garbage collection more efficient by using fewer objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clear answer. As i'm doing this kind of loops for thousand of objects that can be quite heavy, i will probably "unload" a lot the garbage collector by switching to the third option.